# how to enumerate / zip as lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Is there a way to replace the for-loop in the `groupList` function with a lambda function, perhaps with `map()`, in Python 3.

```
def groupList(input_list, output_list=[]):
    for i, (v, w) in enumerate(zip(input_list[:-2], input_list[2:])):
        output_list.append(f'{input_list[i]} {input_list[i+1]} {input_list[i+2]}')
    return output_list

print(groupList(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']))
```

(Output from the `groupList` function would be `['A B C', 'B C D', 'C D E', 'D E F', 'E F G']`)

Comment: Not related, but I don't recommend using a mutable container as a default argument. An alternative is to use `None` instead, and set to an empty list in the function.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it a bad idea to use a mutable container as a default argument?

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
def groupList(input_list):
    return [' '.join(input_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(input_list) - 2)]
```

Solution 2:

```
def groupList(input_list):
    return list(map(' '.join, (input_list[i:i+3] for i in range(len(input_list) - 2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the previous solutions, a more efficient (but less concise) solution is to compute a full concatenation first and then slice it.

```
from itertools import accumulate

def groupList(input_list):
    full_concat = ' '.join(input_list)
    idx = [0]
    idx.extend(accumulate(len(s) + 1 for s in input_list))
    return [full_concat[idx[i]:idx[i+3]-1] for i in range(len(idx) - 3)]
```